# Program is stuck in the FFmpeg call

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have Flask API that receives a wav file and then send it to function (in another file):

```
audio_file = request.files['audio_file']
audio_file_read = audio_file.read()
bytes_io = io.BytesIO(audio_file_read)
load_audio(bytes_io)
```

---

```
def load_audio(bytes_io: bytes, sr: int = 16000):
    
    try:
        print("Trying FFmpeg call...")
        out, _ = (
            ffmpeg.input('pipe:', format='wav', stdin=bytes_io)
            .output("-", format="s16le", acodec="pcm_s16le", ac=1, ar=sr)
            .run(cmd=["ffmpeg", "-nostdin"], capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True)
        )
        print("FFmpeg call successful")
    except ffmpeg.Error as e:
        raise RuntimeError(f"Failed to load audio: {e.stderr.decode()}") from e
    return 'finished'
```

I get this logs:

```
<_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000018B00834040>
Trying FFmpeg call..
```

Why don't I receive other logs? How can I solve it?

Comment: When using `pipe:` as input, FFmpeg doesn't know when to end. We have to close `stdin ` pipe, or execute `communicate()` method. Try `process = ffmpeg.input( ... ).output.run_async(pipe_stdin=True, pipe_stdout=True)` and `process.stdin.write(bytes_io.read())` and `out = process.communicate()[0]`. Remove `stdin=bytes_io` and remove `"-nostdin"`, remove `capture_stdout=True, capture_stderr=True`. Note: It's going to work only with small WAV size. Where did you find a code sample that uses `stdin=bytes_io`?

Comment: Thank you, Rotem! I will try this. That code that I posted was AI'suggestion :)